# concatenate two variables in terraform

Tags: terraform

i'm trying to create a kubernetes cluster from kops using terraform,following code is a part of infrastructure, i'm trying to create the name concatenate with two variables, and i'm getting illegal char error line two, error happens because im trying to define the name with concatenate variables. is it possible in terraform?

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "master-kubernetes" {
  name                 = "master-"${var.zone}".masters."${var.cluster_name}""
  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.master-kubernetes.id}"
  max_size             = 1
  min_size             = 1
  vpc_zone_identifier  = ["${aws_subnet.subnet-kubernetes.id}"]
```

Answer (score 25):

With latest terraform 0.12.x [terraform format doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/format.html) , you could do better like:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "master-kubernetes" {
    name = format("master-%s.masters.%s", var.zone, var.cluster_name)
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "master-kubernetes" {
  name = "master-${var.zone}.masters.${var.cluster_name}"
  # ... other params ...
}
```

Comment: In new version Terraform the declaration var is that same: var.name_var. But, using ${} how in the old version, the Terraform work. Is ok?

Comment: The syntax of Terraform in my answer was based on version 0.11.x and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I would say rather concatenating at resource level use the locals first define a variable in locals and then you can utilize it at resource level

**Locals declaration**

```
locals {
  rds_instance_name = "${var.env}-${var.rds_name}"
}
```

**Resource Level declaration**

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "default_mssql" {
  count                     = var.db_create ? 1 : 0
  name                      = local.rds_instance_name
........
}
```

This is as simple as its need to be ....